# Spring Jedis connection not returned to pool

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, redis, spring-transactions

My app is made of a Spring rest controller calling a service using redis.
I am using spring boot starter redis 1.2.5 and I have defined a template in my beans.xml file:

```
<bean id="jedisConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory"
    p:host-name="${spring.redis.host}"
    p:use-pool="true" 
    p:port="${spring.redis.port}"
/>

<bean id="redisTemplateForTransaction" class="org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate"
    p:connection-factory-ref="jedisConnectionFactory"
    p:keySerializer-ref="stringRedisSerializer"
    p:valueSerializer-ref="jsonRedisSerializerForTransaction"
    p:enableTransactionSupport="true">
    <qualifier value="redisTemplateForTransaction" />
</bean>
```

When I launch more than 8 queries my app blocks. I understand I have reached the default number of connections in the pool.

Why aren't the connections returned automatically at the end of the request processing ?

How to work in a transactional mode so that any incoming request will get its redis connection and return it at the end of the processing ?

Answer (score 4):

You need to enable transaction management for your application by providing a `PlatformTransactionManager` bean.

The easiest way to do so is adding `@EnableTransactionManagement` to your Spring Boot application. If that's not possible, configure a `PlatformTransactionManager` bean. Reusing an existing `DataSourceTransactionManager` is the easiest way. If you do not use a JDBC-compliant database, simply drop in a H2 in-memory database.

If you want to use a JTA transaction manager, see this blog post: https://spring.io/blog/2011/08/15/configuring-spring-and-jta-without-full-java-ee/

HTH, Mark

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, I will try it and let you know.

Comment: But what is very surprising is that we don't have control on the connection pool to simply call returnResource or returnResourceObject.

Comment: Spring Data Redis hides the client details. The issue is, once the a transactional request is started, the transaction/connection is not released if no transaction manager is configured.